# Convert tabs to spaces results in a git merge conflict

Tags: git, tabs, merge, spaces, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm trying to move a project from indenting with tabs to spaces.

How can I merge this without resulting in a merge conflict with every commit from other developers which are using the code base with tabs?

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/eevee/6721177) "HowTo" but step 3 is a little bit unclear for me so I'm not sure if this solution is working or the "best" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the team rebase their changes onto your new master conmmit (maybe tagged as "Indent with Spaces!"), so that new new merges won't have the conflicts.

Mind you 'they' may be annoyed at having to do extra work they thought you were going to do - http://www.columbia.edu/~sss31/rainbow/whose.job.html

No doubt you have a tool to do the conversion... that they can also use for style checking / correction.